# How to make an .exe file from C++ source code using an adroid phone & the app Cxxdroid

Tags: c++, android-source

So I am trying to get an .exe file to the C++ source code I have made. I need to share the program but don't want to share the source code and having this person steal my work. I am using an app called Cxxdroid (Inly own an android phone right now) but can't find any option to get the .exe file to my program.

Comment: Androids are Linux-based and don't use the exe extension to determine whether a file is executable or not.

Answer (score 1):

As user4581301 said you're using  Android, which is based on Linux

You need to compile your source code to an executable file(.exe) with a compiler

To do this, you must use a compiler such as [GCC](https://www.mingw-w64.org/)
or use IDEs like [DevC++](https://www.bloodshed.net/)